# porque mi onClick no funciona?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero que al presionar el botón "Aquí" desaparezcan los inputs  utilizando javaScript, pero no funciona.

```html
<div class="cuerpoLogin">
  <label id="loginLabel">Inicio de sesión</label>
  <input type="email" class="inputs" placeholder="name@example.com">
  <input type="password" class="inputs" placeholder="Contraseña">
  <button id="buttonLogin" type="button">Iniciar sesión</button>
  <div class="registro">
    <p>Registrate<br>
      <button id="buttonR" onclick="myFunction()" type="button" name="button">Aquí</button>
    </p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementByClassName("inputs").style.display = 'none';
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba con `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: La función es `getElementsByClassName`, te faltó la "s"

Comment: Negativo tampoco es eso:(

Comment: El depurador me suelta esto: "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "display", document.getElementsByClassName(...).style is undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error es que es document.getElement**s**ByClassName (getElement S ByClassName)

El segundo es que esa función retorna algo similar a un array de elementos (sin ser enteramente un array). Es decir NO es un solo elemento.

Recomiendo cambiar por querySelectorAll y usar un forEach, corto y simple

```html
<div class="cuerpoLogin">
  <label id="loginLabel">Inicio de sesión</label>
  <input type="email" class="inputs" placeholder="name@example.com">
  <input type="password" class="inputs" placeholder="Contraseña">
  <button id="buttonLogin" type="button">Iniciar sesión</button>
  <div class="registro">
    <p>Registrate<br>
      <button id="buttonR" onclick="myFunction()" type="button" name="button">Aquí</button>
    </p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".inputs").forEach(e => {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        });
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás intentando acceder a solo una clase con **`getElementByClassName()`**. Lo correcto sería usar **`getElementsByClassName()`** para coleccionar todas las clases. Ahora para aplicarle los estilos, puedes hacerlo con el ciclo **`for`** para darle los estilos a cada clase coleccionada:

```html
<div class="cuerpoLogin">
  <label id="loginLabel">Inicio de sesión</label>
  <input type="email" class="inputs" placeholder="name@example.com" />
  <input type="password" class="inputs" placeholder="Contraseña" />
  <button id="buttonLogin" type="button">Iniciar sesión</button>
  <div class="registro">
    <p>
      Registrate
      <button id="buttonR" onclick="myFunction()" type="button" name="button">
        Aquí
      </button>
    </p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputs');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i+=1){
          inputs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```